# Pinch Zoom in iPad using EXT JS 5

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, pinchzoom, extjs5

I have created an EXT JS 5 application. But when i open it in iPad, then i cannot do any pinch zoom. How can i enable pinck zoom in iPad.

```
 Its available in Api docs(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.event.gesture.Pinch).        
 But how can i add it into an EXTJS 5 application.
```

If anyone know some good example to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported by Sencha team, they haven't included the pinch zoom functionality yet. It is disabled by default.

Here is a thread describing the same issue: `http://sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287219`. Here is the comment from Sencha engineering team:

> "Since zoom is handled internally by each browser, we have to make considerations for each. I know it is being look at, but I do not have any dates."

Comment: Please, provide a link to a document or page, where your information can be verified. Any source, please.

Comment: Here is a thread describing the same issue: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287219.
And I had discussion with Sencha team and below the response I got from the engineering team:
---------------------------------

Please see the following post as their seems to be an issue with this at the moment. 

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?287219 

Since zoom is handled internally by each browser, we have to make considerations for each. I know it is being look at, but I do not have any dates.

Comment: Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is great! Consider editing your answer and including most important information from your comments into it. Thanks! :>

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to those events on `Ext.dom.Element`. In any component you can do that for example in render event handler or anywhere after component is rendered:

```
render: function () {
    this.el.on('pinch', function() {
        alert('pinch');
    });
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/y75419xk/2/